# remote validation using jquery.validation.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form using jquery.validate.min.js plugin.

I have used remote method to validate mobile already exists or not. I have used below code

```
 $('#userprofileform').validate({
 rules:
"UserForm[mobile]": {
    remote: {
        url: "<?php echo Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/profile/check-mobile'; ?>",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            mobile: function(){ return $("#userform-mobile").val(); }
        }
    }
 },
},
messages: {
'UserForm[mobile]':{
    remote:"Mobile already exists"
}

},
});
```

On click of submit I have written below code:

```
$('.userprofilesubmit').click(function(){
  if (!$('#userprofileform').valid() === true){
   return false;
  }
 });
```

The validation is working fine. It is showing message. but form is getting submitted twice. If I remove remote validation then form is getting submitted only once. I have observed that using remote function form is getting submitted twice. How too avoid this?

Comment: Show the relevant HTML of the form.

Comment: Why do you have a click handler?   The plugin captures the click and submits automatically.  Your click handler is likely the cause of the double submit.

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting?   Inspected the DOM to see what URL is being generated for your `remote` option?

Answer (score 0):

Remote is an ajax call which results 'true' or 'false' in the response. Hence, If you are submitting the form in ajax and whenever the response is true form is getting submitted. If you have 4 remote validation for 4 fields then form will get submitted 4 times.

Hence whenever you write remote validation use `async:false` to avoid form submission as below

```
 $('#userprofileform').validate({
   rules:
   "UserForm[mobile]": {
      remote: {
      url: "<?php echo Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/profile/check-mobile'; ?>",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        mobile: function(){ return $("#userform-mobile").val(); }
      },
      async: false,
     }
    },
   },
 messages: {
   'UserForm[mobile]':{
   remote:"Mobile already exists"
  }
 },
});
```